# How to open/close clicked div generating inside loop with angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having my divs generating inside ng repeat tag like accordion and now on click of particular div I want to show/hide that clicked div only.

This is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in Data" class="accordion">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="accordion-text">{{ ::item.Name }}</td>
      <td>
        <button ng-click="closeClickedDiv()"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

//div 1
<div ng-show="showDiv" style="height:30px;"></div>


//div 2
<div ng-repeat-end ng-show="showDiv">
  <div class="accordion-data" ng-repeat="item1 in item.SubData">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="shot{{$index}}"></div>
          <div class=" accordion-data">{{ ::item1.subName }}</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
  $scope.showDiv = false;//by default all divs will be closed

 $scope.closeClickedDiv = function () {
      $scope.showDiv = !$scope.showDiv;
    };
```

But here problem is when I click on 1 div all divs get opened.I want to open/close clicked div on this button click.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'hide' property binded to the item, not the scope:

```
$scope.closeClickedDiv = function (item) {
  item.hide = !item.hide;
};

<button ng-click="closeClickedDiv(item)"></button>

<div ng-hide="item.hide" style="height:30px;"></div>
```

Comment: so i should declare this showDiv  property inside my item array??

Comment: no need to be declared, just set initial state for example in an ngInit directive, or invert the logic, use a notVisible property and ng-hide directive

Comment: Sorry can you please add in your answer as i am new in angular js

Answer (score 0):

Call a method on ng-click and pass `$index` in it

```
ng-click="ShowDetailed($index)"
```

Now declare empty array and pass this in ng-show

```
ng-show="detailedShow[$index]"
```

Here is the method -
What it does
1. Will open on click and close on second click
2. If you opened first and clicked on second, it will close first and open second.

```
$scope.detailedShow = [];
var lastIndex = null;
var currentIndex = null;
$scope.ShowDetailed = function(index) {
  currentIndex = index;
  if (lastIndex) {
    if (lastIndex !== currentIndex) {
      if ($scope.detailedShow[lastIndex]) {
        $scope.detailedShow[lastIndex] = !$scope.detailedShow[lastIndex];
      }
      $scope.detailedShow[index] = !$scope.detailedShow[index];
      lastIndex = currentIndex;
    } else {
      $scope.detailedShow[index] = !$scope.detailedShow[index];
    }
  } else {
    $scope.detailedShow[index] = !$scope.detailedShow[index];
    lastIndex = currentIndex;
  }
};
```